# Metodo para extraer datos de un Set en Java

Tags: java

Estoy creando un metodo para extraer valores de un **Set de clients**, los valores en cuestión son los **ID** de todos los clients presentes en el Set, el ID se obtiene llamando **getClientID()**.

Mi metodo:

```
public String[] extractIDsFromClientSet(Set<Client> clients) {
    Client[] arrayClients = (Client[]) clients.toArray();
    String[] clientIDs = new String[clients.size()];

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayClients.length; i++) {
        clientIDs[i] = arrayClients[i].getClientID();
    }
    return clientIDs;
}
```

Al usar mi metodo obtengo la siguiente exepcion:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Lmodels.Client;
at view.userPanes.UserView.extractIDsFromClientSet(UserView.java:128)
at view.userPanes.UserView.setFieldData(UserView.java:82)
```

Como corrijo mi metodo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como dijo Jack el Destripador, vayamos por partes:

#### toArray()

```
(Client[]) clients.toArray();
```

`Object[] Set.toArray()` devuelve un `Object[]`. Aunque todos los elementos del `Object[]` sean instancias de `Client`, eso es algo que el JVM no controla así que falla el *casting*. Este método estaba antes de Java 5 así que no se pudo cambiar la interface para que usará *generics* ya que eso causaría errores en el código ya existente.

La solución es usar la versión *generics* del método, que es `T[] Set.toArray(T[] a)`. Le pasas un `Client[]` (aunque sea de longitud `0`) y el te devolverá una instancia de `Client[]`. Si le pasas ya inicialmente un array de tamaño adecuado, te devolverá ese mismo array.

Así que

```
clients.toArray(new Client[0]);
```

o incluso

```
clients.toArray(new Client[clients.size()]);
```

Por supuesto, otra opción es redefinir el array para que sea `Object[]` y hacer el *cast* en el `for`

```
Object[] arrayClients = (Object[]) clients.toArray();
...
for (int i = 0; i < arrayClients.length; i++) {
    clientIDs[i] = ((Client) arrayClients[i]).getClientID();
}
```

#### Iterable

Pero lo mejor es que, al igual que muchas colecciones, `Set` ya implementa `Iterable`, así que no necesitas la conversión a [] sino que puedes usar un *enhanced for*.

```
int i = 0;
for (Client client : clients) {
   clientsIDs[i] = client.getClientID();
   i++;
}
```

o la versión clásica (aunque recomiendo el *enhanced for*):

```
for(Iterator<Cliente> it = clients.iterator(); int i = 0; it.hasNext(); i++) {
    clientsIDs[i] = it.next().getClientID();
 }
```

Comment: Genial el metodo con el enhanced for!